# how to perform d3 drag and drop

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Having Issue with d3.drag for angular 4. whenever I drag the rectangle object , it is moving fine for first time. After release of mousepress and again trying to drag the rectangle, it is going back to previous event and not able to make mouse control on draggable object. Please give solution to my problem.

```
import { Component,Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import * as d3 from 'd3';  
interface LineData{
  xVal: number,
  yVal:number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  template:'<svg height="500" width="500" ></svg>',
  styleUrl: [] 
})

export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data : LineData[];
  private parentNativeElement : any;
  constructor(private element:ElementRef) { 
      this.parentNativeElement = element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var width = 300;
    var height = 300;
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10}

    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
        .scale(y)
        .ticks(5);

    var valueline:any = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d['xVal']);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d['yVal']);
        });
        console.log(valueline);

    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    d3.select(this.parentNativeElement)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");

    // Get the data
    var data = [
                  {
                    "xVal": 1,
                    "yVal": 2
                  },
                  {
                    "xVal": 2,
                    "yVal": 4
                  },
                  {
                    "xVal": 3,
                    "yVal": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "xVal": 4,
                    "yVal": 5
                  },
                  {
                    "xVal": 5,
                    "yVal": 3
                  }
              ];

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data,
        function (d) {
            return d.xVal;
        }));
    y.domain([
        0, d3.max(data,
            function (d) {
                return d.yVal;
            })
    ]);
     let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

     svg.append("path").datum(data).attr("class","path")// Add the valueline path.
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", valueline(data)).attr("class", "line");


    let rectangle:any = d3.range(1).map(function(){
        return{
            x: Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
            y: Math.floor(Math.random()*height)
        };
    });

    console.log(rectangle);

   let dragRect = svg.selectAll('g').data(rectangle).enter().append("g")

    dragRect.append("rect")
    .attr("x",function(d){return d['x'];})
    .attr("y",function(d){return d['y'];})
    .attr("height",50)
    .attr("width",50).style("fill", "steelblue");

   svg.selectAll('g').attr("transform", 
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")").data(rectangle)
    .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));


    function dragstarted(d){
        d3.select(this).raise().classed("active",true);
    }



    function dragged(d){
        d.xVal = x.invert(d3.event.x);
        d.yVal = y.invert(d3.event.y);
        d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x", x(d.xVal))
        .attr("y", y(d.yVal))
        .attr("transform","translate("+d.xVal+","+d.yVal+")")
        console.log(d); 
    }


    function dragended(d){
        d3.select(this).raise().classed("active",false);
        //d3.select('rect#no-drag').on('mousedown.drag',null);
    }



    svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis"`enter code here`)
        .call(yAxis);
  }

}
```

Comment: This is for Line chart having draggable object (rectangle). on moving the rectangle , dragged axis values will be rendered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem seems to be that `dragged` function is not remembering the x & y between successive drag events.

To do this, you need

```js
d3.select(this)
  .attr("x", d.x = x(d.xVal))
  .attr("y", d.y = y(d.yVal))
```

instead of

```js
d3.select(this)
  .attr("x", x(d.xVal))
  .attr("y", y(d.yVal))
```

---

Run this code snippet to check it out

```js
console.clear()
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10}

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).scale(x).ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).scale(y).ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) { return x(d['xVal']); })
  .y(function (d) { return y(d['yVal']); });

var svg = d3.select("svg");
d3.select(this.parentNativeElement)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g");

// Get the data
var data = [
  {
    "xVal": 1,
    "yVal": 2
  },
  {
    "xVal": 2,
    "yVal": 4
  },
  {
    "xVal": 3,
    "yVal": 1
  },
  {
    "xVal": 4,
    "yVal": 5
  },
  {
    "xVal": 5,
    "yVal": 3
  }
];

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data,
  function (d) {
    return d.xVal;
  }));
y.domain([
    0, d3.max(data,
        function (d) {
            return d.yVal;
        })
]);

let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

svg.append("path").datum(data).attr("class","path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", valueline(data)).attr("class", "line");

let rectangle = d3.range(3).map(function() {
  return {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random()*height)
  };
});

let dragRect = svg.selectAll('g').data(rectangle).enter()
  .append("g")

dragRect.append("rect")
  .attr("x",function(d){return d['x'];})
  .attr("y",function(d){return d['y'];})
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .style("fill", "steelblue")

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .data(rectangle)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended)
  );

const dragBounds = {}
const tickHeight = 10;

function setDragBounds(subject) {
  dragBounds.top = 0 - margin.top;
  dragBounds.left = 0 - margin.left;
  dragBounds.bottom = height - tickHeight - subject.attr('height');
  dragBounds.right = width - margin.right - subject.attr('width');
}

function dragstarted(d){
  /* 
    Calculate drag bounds at dragStart because it's one event vs many 
    events if done in 'dragged()'
  */    
  setDragBounds(d3.select(this)) 
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d){
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", getX(d.x = d3.event.x) )
    .attr("y", getY(d.y = d3.event.y) );
}

function getX(x) {
  return x < dragBounds.left ? dragBounds.left
    : x > dragBounds.right ? dragBounds.right 
    : x
}

function getY(y) {
  return y < dragBounds.top ? dragBounds.top
    : y > dragBounds.bottom ? dragBounds.bottom 
    : y
}

function dragended(d){
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}

svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg height="500" width="500" ></svg>
```

Note I attached the drag events to `rect` instead of `g`, which I assume was a typo.

---

### Keeping within bounds

To constrain the drag to bounds the way I found works best is a max/min function on the x & y values.

```js
function dragged(d){
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", getX(d.x = d3.event.x) )
    .attr("y", getY(d.y = d3.event.y) );
}

function getX(x) {
  return x < dragBounds.left ? dragBounds.left
    : x > dragBounds.right ? dragBounds.right 
    : x
}

function getY(y) {
  return y < dragBounds.top ? dragBounds.top
    : y > dragBounds.bottom ? dragBounds.bottom 
    : y
}
```

Bounds are set at drag start to avoid repetition of any calculation.

```js
const dragBounds = {}
const tickHeight = 10;

function setDragBounds(subject) {
  dragBounds.top = 0 - margin.top;
  dragBounds.left = 0 - margin.left;
  dragBounds.bottom = height - tickHeight - subject.attr('height');
  dragBounds.right = width - margin.right - subject.attr('width');
}

function dragstarted(d){
  /* 
    Calculate drag bounds at dragStart because it's one event vs many 
    events if done in 'dragged()'
  */    
  setDragBounds(d3.select(this)) 
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}
```

Comment: And how can I set that draggable rectangle object only specified to x and y axis ? how can i set that , it should not move outside of axis or line path ?

Comment: Good question, please see footnote.

Comment: Richard Matsen - it works for me . thank you so much . I learned it.